# How to stop Edge from automatically downloading source mapped UI5 library files (*-dbg.js)?

Tags: sapui5, microsoft-edge

Opening up the developer menu (F12) in Edge instantly triggers Edge to start downloading all source map files. I mean all, all individual js files e.g. sap/m/Button-dbg.js.

It freezes up the browser and makes it impossible to do performance network tracing using the built in developer tools.

How can I stop this from doing that automatically?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open MS Edge
2. Browse to https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/orderbrowser/webapp/test/mockServer.html
3. Once the webpage is completely loaded, press F12
4. You now notice it starts downloading all source map files for the UI5 framework (*-dbg.js)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows 10 1809 with Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0**

source map files are downloaded unasked for

**Windows 10 1909 with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0:**

no issues

Answer (score 0):

In the app open STRG+ALT+SHIFT+S to open UI5 Dev. Tools, then -> Technical Settings -> Turn Debug-Sources off.

[image]

Comment: I double checked to be sure, but the Debug Sources is already set to OFF.